# How to implement Dynamic regression Forecasting using only lagged values of the dependent variable

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, dynamic-regression

I understand that Regression with Arima errors which is also called Dynamic regression is normally implemented using exogeneous variables, is it possible to implement dynamic regression using only endogenous variables? And how would this be implemented?

Bellow is the regression equation using exogenous variables (Independent variables)

\begin{align}y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1,t} + \dots + \beta_k x_{k,t} + \varepsilon_t \hspace{1.5cm}(1.1)\end{align}

And This bellow is the dynamic regression equation where $\eta_t$ is an ARIMA(1,1,1) process.

\begin{align*}
  y_t &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1,t} + \dots + \beta_k x_{k,t} + \eta_t,\hspace{1.25cm} (2.1) \\
      & (1-\phi_1B)(1-B)\eta_t = (1+\theta_1B)\varepsilon_t,
\hspace{1cm} (2.2)
\end{align*}

How is $\eta_t$ calculated ? Since if I transform the back-shift notation to in equation 2.2 I should get the following:

\begin{align}\eta_t = \varepsilon_t + \theta_1\varepsilon_{t-1} + \eta_{t-1} + \phi_1(\eta_{t-1} - \eta_{t-2}) \hspace{0.36cm} (2.3)\end{align}

Is it possible to transform equation 2.1 to use endogenous variables (Dependent variables) as follows:

\begin{align}y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 y_{t-1} + \dots + \beta_k y_{t-k} + \eta_t \hspace{1.2cm}(3.1)\end{align}

Questions:

1. How would 3.1 be implemented differently compared to 1.1 other than replacing all exogenous variables to endogenous variables?
2. Is the polynomial notation shown in equation 2.3 for ARIMA(1,1,1) correct ?

Comment: Just use an autoregressive (AR) or an autoregressive moving-average (ARMA) model. Function `auto.arima` in the `forecast` package in R is one way to implement this.

Comment: I see, but my understanding is that the AR or ARMA models include white-noise innovation residuals which are not auto-correlated, whereas dynamic regression has innovation residuals that are auto-correlated as an ARIMA process, this is the link https://otexts.com/fpp2/dynamic.html

Comment: Correct. But what is there not to like about white-noise residuals?

Comment: I have no issues with white-noise residuals, but mainly was trying make those residuals correlated with each other to replicate dynamic regression.

Comment: No need for that, as the correlation is modelled through the AR and MA terms.

Comment: How can that be implemented on the white-noise series? i.e. given the white-noise series how can we find an appropriate ARIMA model for it, is it as simple as taking the white-noise series and running `auto.arima` on it then combining it with an AR model?

Comment: For white noise, the optimal ARIMA model is ARIMA(0,0,0), thus a constant-only model. Not fancy at all. But is your series white noise?

Comment: That’s the thing I’m not sure if the residuals are white-noise, they could be auto-correlated, in the best case if they are white noise then ARIMA(0,0,0) would work well.

Comment: The nice thing about ARIMA is that if you select the lag orders appropriately, the residuals will be white noise. And if they are not white noise, you just need to change the lag orders to make them white noise. Refer to [Wold's decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_decomposition) and the fact that ARMA can parsimoniously approximate MA.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help.

Comment: Rashad: I can answer the first question. You can't transform 2.1 to an equation with lagged $y_t$ because, in 2.1, all of the $x_t$ are contemporaneous with the response $y_t$. I'm not clear what you're after but you may want to google for "koyck distributed lag". That's a model that accounts for effects that keep effecting even after the contemporaneous period is over. But,  equation 2.1, as it currently is, doesn't imply that behavior so it cannot be written as a distributed lag ( which is kind of what your first question was ).

Comment: @mlofton: I understand what you mean by that $x_{n,t}$ occur at the same time as $y_t$. I guess that regression is restricted to situations where $x_{n,t}$ is contemporaneous with response $y_t$. However, what I am asking is if it's possible to have an auto-regression where the error term $\varepsilon_t$ is replaced with $\eta_t$ so that the error terms are auto-correlated? Could this be regarded as Dynamic Auto-Regression? And What would be the benefits of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rashad: I'll write this here even though it's not an answer.

Suppose one had a distributed lag model such as:

$y_t = \rho y_{t-1} + x_t + \epsilon_t$.

This kind of look like a harmless regression with independent errors.
But, now, re-write it using the lag operator. One obtains:

$y_t = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \rho^{i} x_{t-i} + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \rho^{i} \epsilon_{t-i}$

So, my point is that the inclusion of a lagged dependent variable ( in this case, $y_{t-1}$ ), actually implies a correlated response in the "transformed"
version of the model. So, a lagged dependent variable is a way of dealing with past errors and $x's$ that continue to have a lagged effect and are NOT just contemporaneous. I hope that helps as far as what I'm trying to say but I'm not even sure if it's relevant to your problem. I think it answers the first question hopefully which is that you're current model does not account for errors that continue to have a lagged effect after their initial occurrence.

Andrew Harvey's "Econometric Analysis of Time Series", an underrated text, covers this type of material. Most econometric texts and statistics time series texts don't, atleast at the level that Harvey does.